# How to send the details of a given link as a parameter to another jsp page?

Tags: java, javascript, sql, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to link a product from the category.jsp page to its own product.jsp page. When I click on a given product on the category page, the link in the browser displays perfectly as supposed to: `http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/product?389` but the issue: I receive a `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error`. I know it's because it's not finding the page, but after trying several solutions... I seem to not be able to find the piece of code that would make a difference... Any help would be much appreciated

The Controller Servlet:

```
package controller;


import cart.ShoppingCart;
import wishlist.Wishlist;
import entity.Category;
import entity.Product;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import session.CategoryFacade;
import session.ProductFacade;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @EJB
    private CategoryFacade categoryFacade;
    @EJB
    private ProductFacade productFacade;

@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Category selectedCategory;
    Product selectedProduct;
    Collection<Product> categoryProducts;

 // if product page is requested
        if (userPath.equals("/product")) {

            // get productId from request
            String productId = request.getQueryString();

            if (productId != null) {

                // get selected product
                selectedProduct = productFacade.find(Short.parseShort(productId));

                // place selected product in session scope
                session.setAttribute("selectedProduct", selectedProduct);
            }
```

This is the code from the category.jsp to call the product:

```
<a href="product?${product.id}"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg"></a>
```

Full Category.jsp:

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts}" varStatus="iter">

<td>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td
style="vertical-align: middle; width: 180px; text-align: center; height: 180px;"
class="cell"><a href="product?${product.id}"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg"></a><br>
</td>
<td
style="vertical-align: middle; width: 140px; text-align: center;">${product.name}<br>
</td>
<td
style="vertical-align: middle; width: 125px; text-align: center;">$
${product.price}<br>
</td>
<td
style="vertical-align: middle; width: 125px; text-align: center;">

    <form action="addToWishlist" method="post"><br><br> <input
name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> 

    <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit"> </form>
<br>
</td>
<td
style="vertical-align: middle; width: 123px; text-align: center;">


    <form action="addToCart" method="post"><br><br> 

    <input name="productId"
value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>"
type="submit"> 


</form>
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is the Product.jsp (destination page):

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; height: 172px;" border="0"
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">



<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;">product_gallery<br>
</td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="6" style="vertical-align: top;"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productBigImagePath}${product.name}.jpg"><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.name}<br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">$ ${selectedProduct.price}</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;">${selectedProduct.description}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><form action="addToWishlist" method="post"><br><br> <input
name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> 

    <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToWishlist'/>" type="submit"> </form><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><form action="addToCart" method="post"><br><br> 

    <input name="productId"
value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> <input class="submit" value="<fmt:message key='AddToCart'/>"
type="submit"> 


</form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><br>
</td>

<td colspan="2" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top;"><ul><li style="background-color: rgb(198, 255, 201); width:100%; text-align:center; border-radius:2em;"><a href="${value}"><fmt:message key='ContinueShopping'/></a></li>
                            </ul><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue myself. I forgot to add the parameter in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>/product</url-pattern>


    </servlet-mapping>
```